# Adding code for tracking events (iOS)

Tags: ios, sdk, analytics, tracking

I would like to add a code for a background service which may track all events (names of current View Controller, name of called method when executed, etc...). It is a little bit like analytics api but in some way different.
I have successfully programmed a background service with NSTimer which execute every 5 secondes, but I can't figure out how to detect executed actions on the device (I have tried to see console log, but nothing there !)
Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Asking the SO community here, but could this be done with Crashalitcs Custom Keys: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92520-how-do-i-use-custom-keys ?

Comment: does the Crashalitics Custom Keys do the trick?